# check rcode and pipe in bash

Tags: bash, pipe

I want to do this:

```
./first.sh
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
exit
fi
# pipe output of first.sh to second.sh
```

So `second.sh` shouldn't run unless `first.sh` succeeds but I don't really know where to pipe the output of `first.sh` to in the mean time.

Comment: Disc space usage, concurrency issues, etc.  While that does work I'm guessing there's a better practice here.

Comment: I don't think so honestly. it's pretty standard.  You could store the output in a variable by doing tmpstr="$(./first.sh)" and then do echo "$tmpstr" | second.sh but this can introduce escaping issues sometimes if you are not careful.  You pretty much have to do one of these things because any variation of using a pipe will start sending input to second.sh before first.sh finishes

Comment: Pipes are used to reduce processing time, by allowing process2 to nibble on the output from process1 as it is created. If you must be certain that all of process1 was clean, before starting p2, then you have to take the extra time (by not piping), to write tmp file, and then pass them onto the next step. Either that, or you have build process2 so it can recognize a problem in input from process1, and be able to rollback any changes already made. No easy answer for that. Are you sure it's all that critical? Maybe some other method to test results from p2, and halt? Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not dump it to a file, and then write that into `second.sh` if `first.sh` succeeds ?

```
./first.sh > /tmp/first.pid 
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
   exit
fi   
./second.sh < /tmp/first.pid
```

You may want to scope your file with a pid or similar if concurrency is an issue.

Comment: There really isn't a better, portable way. I'd +1 if you also fix the Useless Use of `$?` -- the idiomatic way to write that is `if first.sh; then ...` or perhaps more realistically `first.sh >/tmp/first.pid || { rm -f /tmp/first.pid; exit $?; }; second.sh </tmp/first.pid` ... and you should use a proper temp file name.

Comment: Good use of pid - better to use file descriptors 3 and above but yes this is the proper way to make the first and second process synchronous.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `bash` option `pipefail` to cause an error and exit to be reported when a command in a pipe fails:

```
set -e # Set exit on error
set -o pipefail # Set exit on error to work with pipes
```

[Source of information](http://petereisentraut.blogspot.co.uk/2010/11/pipefail.html).

Comment: but all the commands in the pipeline will already be running so second.sh will already have partially run.  That might be ok for him but it is different semantics than he posted